# removing image from a list c#

Tags: c#, image, list, checkbox

I am trying to add an image to a list of images when a checkbox is checked, and when the checkbox is unchecked I want to remove the image from the list.  Adding the image works fine, but when the box is unchecked its not removing the image from the list.

```
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
private void chkRadiation_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (chkRadiation.Checked == true && images.Count < 4)
        {
            images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\joe\documents\radiation.gif"));                
        }
            else if (chkRadiation.Checked == false)
            {                 
                images = images.Where(x => x !=  Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\joe\documents\radiation.gif")).ToList();
            }
            else if
                (chkRadiation.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select only 3 images");
                chkRadiation.Checked = false;
            }               
    }
```

I also tried

```
images.Remove(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\joe\documents\radiation.gif"));
```

It did not work either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the List<T>.Remove() method and read about what type of parameters it receives. ;)

Comment: It says it removes an Image Item.  I tried that and it didn't do what I needed.  When the item is removed I need the list.count() to be reduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're working with instances of a class `Image`, so all your comparisons, and `images.Remove` are working off references.

When you do `Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\joe\documents\radiation.gif")` you're creating a new image object/reference, that happens to contains the same data as one in the list, but because the reference isn't the same, removing it won't work.

You might be better to recode using a `Generic.Dictionary<String,Image>` where the key string is the path of the image (in the absence of any better key). That way you can check if there are items in the dictionary with the path and remove them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

By default List.Remove uses instance value comparision to detect which element to remove.  Since you're loading the image again to remove it, that's a different instance.  I would keep track of the index in which an image is added and use that to remove it from the list.  CheckBox.Tag might be a good place to hide the index...

Answer (score 0):

with the expression

```
x !=  Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\joe\documents\radiation.gif")
```

you compare two objects:

- Object one: x is the image already in your collection.
- Object two: is
  the image which gets create at this moment based on the source path.

as you compare the two it will always return false as these are two different instances of the object Image.

[How the operator == works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/53k8ybth%28v=vs.80%29)